# minikube start {OS type not recognized}

Tags: kubernetes, devops, manjaro

```
minikube start
```

giving below error messaage on Manjaro Deepin ( Arch Linux ).

> E1002 00:02:24.832976   26272 start.go:143] Error starting host:
>   Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: OS type not
>   recognized.

tried it on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04 and VT-X/AMD-v not enable error giving even Virtualbox preference set to VT-X/AMD-v enable.

Note : Need to fix the issue on my local machine not the virtualBox

uname -a output

> Linux xxx-pc 4.9.51-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 20 10:37:40 UTC
>   2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Enable VT-x on your computer's BIOS.
For Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

Comment: I've got the same issue on Antergos  with VT-x enabled. Wonder whether it is a compatibility issue with qemu 3.

Comment: I have got the same issue and double checked the VT-x option in BIOS which is enabled. Also I can SSH into VM. But still facing the same issue. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6):

If working on **Linux**, follow the steps:

Uninstall/delete all minikube related files

```
1. minikube delete
2. rm /usr/local/minikube
3. rm -rf ~/.minikube
```

Then do `minikube start` again. If it doesn't work uninstall & reinstall minikube.

For **Windows** user follow these steps:

1. Do `minikube delete`
2. Delete `C:\Users\username\.minikube` folder.
3. Do `minikube start` again.

**Also**, don't forget to stop all the process related to **`VirtualBox`** including `VBoxHeadless` before deleting minikube.