# minikube installation on windows7 with virtual machine

Tags: kubernetes

I am installing the minikube on windows with virtual box setup I am getting the error as host type not recognized I am new to kubeadm can someone help me out ?

getting the error as similar to below

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

## C:\Users\collabera>minikube.exe start

kubectl could not be found on your path. kubectl is a requirement for using minikube
To install kubectl, please do the following:

download kubectl from:
https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.8.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
Add kubectl to your system PATH

To disable this message, run the following:

## minikube config set WantKubectlDownloadMsg false

Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E1114 10:06:59.401000    1940 start.go:150] Error starting host: Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: O
S type not recognized.

Retrying.
E1114 10:15:01.827000    1940 start.go:150] Error starting host: Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: O
S type not recognized.

Retrying.
E1114 10:23:16.791000    1940 start.go:150] Error starting host: Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: O
S type not recognized.

Retrying.
E1114 10:31:19.130000    1940 start.go:150] Error starting host: Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: O
S type not recognized.

Retrying.
E1114 10:39:21.489000    1940 start.go:150] Error starting host: Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: O
S type not recognized.

Retrying.
E1114 10:39:23.490000    1940 start.go:156] Error starting host:  Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host:
OS type not recognized
Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: OS type not recognized
Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: OS type not recognized
Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: OS type not recognized
Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: OS type not recognized

## C:\Users\collabera>minikube.exe start

kubectl could not be found on your path. kubectl is a requirement for using minikube
To install kubectl, please do the following:

download kubectl from:
https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.8.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
Add kubectl to your system PATH

To disable this message, run the following:

## minikube config set WantKubectlDownloadMsg false

Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E1114 11:49:32.142500    4308 start.go:150] Error starting host: Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: O
S type not recognized.

Retrying.

Comment: It would be great if you took the 5 minutes to format your question as if you cared whether someone read it or not

Comment: You posted what appears to be the exact same snippet twice, without saying whether you followed the instructions plainly written for you: download kubectl.exe, place it in your path.

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515709/minikube-start-os-type-not-recognized) implies VT-x may be disabled on your computer

Comment: hey matthew sorry I got it thanks for replying

Comment: @ashok Please , if you can post your solution, how you got it to work it will help other users of SOF.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed minikube on virtual machine HostOS : windows 7 , Guest : Antix

```
 1. Disable virtualization(VT-X/AMD-v) and PA-NX in virtual machine.
 
 2. As windows 7 doesn't have VT-X flag if it has in your case disable it.
 
 3. sudo apt install conntrack
 
 4. sudo minikube start --driver=none
 
 5. Fire command : kubectl [If you get output like helper command it is installed]
```